# CSS .active & .hover delay?

Tags: html, css

I have a search form with a styled search box and button.  I have the button styled with CSS .active & .hover classes.  Everything is fine and it looks great however, I'm experiencing a short delay between normal, hover & and active states of the search button (the button will blink between states then states will load seamlessly afterwards.

I was wondering if there is a way to load the CSS on page load with a bit of javascript or if there is another method of getting the button to work seamlessly between states.  Any suggestions?

CSS:

```
fieldset.search {
    border: none;
    width: 480px;
    background-image: url(images/searchbackground.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 36px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.search input, .search button {
    border: none;
    float: left;
}
.search input.box {
    color: #690;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 427px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: 7px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    margin-left: 7px;
}
.search button.btn {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: url(images/search.png) no-repeat top right;
}
.search button.btn:hover {
    background: url(images/search_hover.png) no-repeat top right;
}
.search button.btn:active {
    background: url(images/search_active.png) no-repeat top right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="form" action="search.php" method="get">
  <fieldset class="search">
    <input type="text" class="box" name="q" />
    <button class="btn" name="Submit">Search</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: A sprite is by far the best way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are experiencing a flicker effect because the images aren't loaded by default.

To prevent this you may want to look into the next pages:
http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2005/06/22/preload-hover-images-in-css/

And even better is if you use an all-in-one image called a sprite:
http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try, I've head of "sprites" before just never got around to researching what it actually was.  Thanks for the useful links!

Comment: A sprite is basically a lot of images combined into one, then you use different parts of that images for something like different states of your menu cleverly using background position to change the focus to a different part of the image. gl :)

Comment: +1 for sprites. Once you're familiar with the concept, check out http://yostudios.github.com/Spritemapper/ to help automate the process.

Comment: Sprites are good and work well, but for saving time preloading is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can preload the images with javascript/jquery like seen in this: http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript

Comment: If you can you should avoid using javascript for like everything if there are valid css tricks that do the same...